# Deshacer un "merge branch master" a mi "current branch"

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

Estoy trabajando con un branch `B` y tengo el branch `Master`. Acabo de terminar mis modificaciones y quise agregarlas al Master, pero en vez de hacer esto hice un `merge branch 'Master' into 'B'` (Lo pongo en ingles por que no se como traducirlo y por que estoy usando `gitHubDesktop`).

Hice el commit sin resolver los problemas pensando que podía volver al anterior y todo quedaría bien pero ahora tengo un montón de conflictos en mi código fuente. Intente volver al commit anterior, al merge, pero permanecen los cambios. ¿Como puedo volver a este commit sin el Merge que hice del máster?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Puedes ver todos los estados con el comando `git reflog`
el resultado sera una lista de estados con la primera columna siendo el codigo para su respectivo estado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Luego con el comando `git reset --hard {poner codigo de la lista}` puedes volver al estado que tu desees.

por ejemplo para volver al estado HEAD@{2} el comando seria:

```
git reset --hard fbebd80
```

**Nota**: para saber a que estado ir puedes basarte en el comentario de la ultima columna

**Otra solucion alternativa** seria guardar en un borrador, limpiando el branch actual con el comando `git stash save`

Comment: Gracias! Recupere todo. Pero ahora tengo conflictos entre el master y este branch. Creo que puedo hacer este el master, pero crees que sea conveniente? A la hora de hacer el pull request me dice que no se puede hacer automáticamente, tal vez porque hice demasiados cambios.

Comment: @Angel el branch actual tiene errores ? o esta completamente limpio_?

Comment: @Angel ahora puedes limpiar tu rama actual con git stash save y podras hacer git pull

Comment: La rama actual quedó completamente limpia.

Comment: @Angel si sigues teniendo problemas puedes formular otra pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Si es tu caso que hiciste merge por ejemplo de tu rama de desarrollo en qa pero quieres quitar ese merge y dejarla si esos cambios puedes utilizar

```sh
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

con eso puedes hacer un stash o hacer un checkout de los ficheros modificados para o un ***git reset --hard***  mas el codigo del ultimo commit al que quieres retornar.